# Angular | useFactory to pass arguments to service

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm trying to provide a service in the following way:

**my-module.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService} from './my-service.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MyService,
      useFactory: () => new MyService(2),
    },
  ],
})
export class MyModule {}
```

**my-service.service.ts**

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private n: number
  ) {
    console.log(this.n);
  }
}
```

But I receive the following error:

**error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'n' of class 'MyService'.
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.**

There is this workaround, to use `Inject('')`, but this seems weird and is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers-usefactory):

**my-service.service.ts**

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    // weird fix
    @Inject('') private n: number
  ) {
    console.log(this.n);
  }
}
```

The Angular version that I'm using is **13.3.11**

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `useValue`:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MyService {
      provide: "propertyName",
      useValue: "2",
    }
  ],
})

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('propertyName') private n: string
  ) {
    console.log(this.n);
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#injecting-an-object

Comment: Hi @Ale_Bianco! Thank you, but my real scenario is more complex, I need to use `useFactory` as I'll send some classes that I need to instantiate and configure.

Comment: @GeorgianStan is the same as useValue: https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2018/08/17/using-useclass-usefactory-usevalue-useexisting-with-treeshakeable-providers-in-angular/

Comment: You have to use `useClass` for the classes

Comment: Sure, I see, however I need to execute some code before instantiating MyService. That's why I need useFactory

Comment: Have you tried with Factory providers? https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers-usefactory